# Add wordpress url in href of js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've got code:

```
if ($('.header').width() < 767 ){
  $(".header__search").html('<a href="/cart" class="d-block xxxd"><img src="/wp-content/themes/img/cart.png" width="16px" /><span class="badge badge-warning" id="lblCartCount">'+$('#barba-wrapper > div > header > div.header__main > div > div.header__user > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span').text()+'</span></a>');
});
```

I need to replace url in href `/cart`  to default wordpress :

```
<?php echo wc_get_cart_url() ?>
```

How to put it?

Answer (score 2):

This will work if you put the code in the PHP template file or functions.php.

Example for functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_footer_javascript', 99 );
function wp_footer_javascript(){
?>
<script> 
if ($('.header').width() < 767 ){
    $(".header__search").html('<a href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url() ?>" ...');
});
</script>
<?php
}
```